# Iphone UIPickerView: Change selector height

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

is it possible to change the selector height on a picker view?

Thanks

Comment: What's a 'selector'? Do you mean the selection indicator (the little transparent-looking band across the middle marking the current selection)?

Comment: yes! and i want to change its height...

Comment: not... anybody seems to know the right answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement this in your picker delegate

```
pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:
```

From [UIPickerViewDelegate Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html):

> Called by the picker view when it needs the row height to use for
>   drawing row content.
>
> ```
> - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
> ```
>
> - Parameters
>
>   pickerView - The picker view requesting this information.
>
>   component - A zero-indexed number identifying a component of
>     pickerView. Components are numbered left-to-right.
>
>   Return Value - A float value indicating the height of the row in
>     points.

Comment: This seems to work in iOS 7. In fact I get the same result whether I select "Show selection indicator" or not. But it at least changes sizes with rowHeightFor Component. In iOS 6 this seems to have no effect on the indicator.

Answer (score -1):

no it is not possible to change the height of SelectionIndicator. the only way to achieve is, to add a custom view on the controller's view(or where-ever you are adding your picker) and animate it with PickerView(because it is not possible to add UIView on top of UIPickerView)